# How to specify environment variables in .csproj file

Tags: msbuild, environment-variables, .net-6.0, monogame, rider

How can I, through the .csproj file, specify environment variables to apply *during* the build, such as when building with Rider?

Specifically, I want to set DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT=1 so that I can build from within the IDE, without resorting to the command line (see below).

Adding `<InvariantGlobalization>true</InvariantGlobalization>` to the project file did not work, since that does not affect the underlying/imported build target, but executing `export DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT=1` before `dotnet build NAME.csproj` worked.

*Background:* A recent distro upgrade on openSuse Tumbleweed bricked MonoGame project builds with the following error message when invoking mgcb (re-installing ICU with Zypper did not fix the issue):

```
Couldn't find a valid ICU package installed on the system. Set the configuration flag System.Globalization.Invariant to true if you want to run with no globalization support.
(...)
error MSB3073: The command "dotnet (...) exited with code 134
```

Edit: I have finally gotten a Target to run before the Nopipeline target using InitialTargets. The problem now is the Exec task runs in a discarded scope.

Comment: The error line is not that useful without context, so which target ran a dotnet-based tool. For tool invocations using things like an `<Exec>` task, the target author could set environment variables

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which task fails, you can hope that the target author added an option to set the environment variables.

E.g. for C# compilation, you could set:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <CscEnvironment>$(CscEnvironment);DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT=1</CscEnvironment>
</PropertyGroup>
```

If the tool is run by a custom target, you would need to author a replacement target that allows setting the environment variable.